# Web scraping over multiple websites

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have data on amazon websites visited stored in a csv and read into R as a data.frame into an object "DataAmazon"

```
DataAmazon <- read.csv("URLs.csv", header = TRUE, comment.char = "", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(DataAmazon,2)  #Top 2 rows of data    
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01L8PLHTI/ref=s9_acsd_hps_bw_c_x_1_w?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-6&pf_rd_r=Z4049X520KCMMB3CNRVG&pf_rd_r=Z4049X520KCMMB3CNRVG&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=83565b89-9e07-44df-a55a-95a45c9b49b5&pf_rd_p=83565b89-9e07-44df-a55a-95a45c9b49b5&pf_rd_i=509908031

https://www.amazon.co.uk/United-Colors-Benetton-2OZ1538Q0-Jacket/dp/B01IP45CAK/ref=sr_1_1?m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&s=clothing&ie=UTF8&qid=1503313547&sr=1-1&nodeID=1730756031&psd=1
```

I am trying to extract the web page title as below from the 1st element of dataframe

```
url <- DataAmazon[1,]

Amazon_Normal_Text1 <- url %>%read_html() %>%html_nodes("title") %>% html_text()
```

My initial try using for loop is

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DataAmazon))
{
  url <- DataAmazon[i, ]
  Amazon_Normal_Text1 <- url %>%read_html() %>%html_nodes("title") %>% html_text()
}
```

How can I use family of apply functions to loop over the csv file which contains about 100 rows of URL's and save the output as another file.

Comment: Scraping Amazon is a violation of their T&C/ToS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that does exactly what on the last block of code

```
amazonTitle <- function(x){
    x %>%read_html() %>% html_nodes("title") %>% html_text()
}
```

Then use `apply` function to do the following :

```
 apply(DataAmazon, 1, amazonTitle)
```